# Trying to update a form in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to update my user's details, but when I submit my changes, my page just refreshes and I don't get the `dd()` that I've put in the function. What happens is that the page refreshes and in my url I will have something like

> test-laravel.test/users/edit/1?_token=wetjwgwgrnregnrgnrn"

My edit.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('users.update', ['user' => $user->id]) }}" method="PUT">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" value="{{ $user->name }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="email" type="text" value="{{ $user->email }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My web.php

```
Route::prefix('users')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/edit/{user}', [ UsersController::class, 'edit' ])->name('users.edit');
    Route::put('/edit/{user}', [ UsersController::class, 'update' ])->name('users.update');
});
```

My update function in my UsersController

```
public function update()
{
    dd(request()->all());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML do not have `PUT`

so

```php
<form action="{{ route('users.update', ['user' => $user->id]) }}" method="PUT">
```

to

```php
<form action="{{ route('users.update', ['user' => $user->id]) }}" method="POST">
@method('PUT')
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Nienna your welcome if it solve your problem mark this thank you